# How can I use eager loading with scope in complicated nested association?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, eager-loading

I have 4 models such as below

- User (has 1 profile, many communities, and many codes)
- Profile (belongs to user)
- Community (has many codes, belongs to user)
- Code (belongs to both community and user)

Now I'm trying to show 10 records of the `code` that belongs to particular community.

This `code` contains external table's info such as

- `username(in user table)`
- `comment(in profile table)`
- `point(in profile table)`

Now, it's issuing many sql queries because I'm not using eager loading.
In this case, how can I customize my code to make this eager loading in order to make load speed faster?

**controllers/communities_controller.rb**

```
#CanCan load_and_authorize_resouce
load_and_authorize_resource :find_by => :community_name,
```

**models/community.rb**

```
belongs_to :user
has_many :codes
```

**models/code.rb**

```
belongs_to :user, counter_cache: true
belongs_to :community, counter_cache: true

scope :recent, lambda { |n = 10| includes(:user).where('users.deleted_at' => nil).order("users.last_active_at DESC").limit(n) }
```

**models/user.rb**

```
has_one :profile
has_many :communities
has_many :codes
```

**models/profile.rb**

```
belongs_to :user
```

**views/communityes/show.html.erb**

```
<% @community.codes.recent.each do |code| %>
    <%= render 'codes/code', {:code => code, :icon_photo => code.user.profile.user_avatar} %>
<% end %>
```

**views/communityes/_code.html.erb**

```
<tr>
    Username: <%= code.user.username %> <br />
    Code: <%= code.data %> <br />
    Comment: <%= code.user.profile.comment %> <br />
    Point: <%= code.user.profile.point.to_s %>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shouldn't be particularly complicated, just `.includes` all the bits you want to eager load ..

```
@community.codes.recent.includes(user: :profile)
```

Also, are a `Community`'s codes always equal to that of all of it's `User`s? If so, you should be using a `has_many :codes, through: :users` association on `Community`.

Comment: Are you sure I don't need to add codes into includes? just like this `@community.codes.recent.includes(user: :profile, codes)`

Comment: Nah you definitely don't need to do that, the codes are what you're loading in the first place. Besides it won't work unless you have an association called `codes` on your `Code` model :), which you don't have and don't want to have.